# Python, operation error, want to make dataframe standard for calculations, it contains: string, integer, float

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

## Python, operation error, want to make dataframe  standard for calculations, it contains: string, integer, float..

Getting errors trying do do simple calculations.
Even when I do transformations, they say it is a series.

### How eliminate a series to have just a normal dataframe

```
# Dataframe

g_spend = 

    id   Campaign_ID   Month  campaignid   cost    leads
0 1664745    154      2019|08  31664745   $34.3    65.0


Data types of the dataframe

g_spend.dtypes

id                    int64
Campaign_ID_name     object
Month                object
Account              object
campaignid           object
campaign_name        object
cost                 object
leads               float64
dtype: object



# Making simple operation

# extract the dolar sign $
#g_spend["cost"] = g_spend["cost"].map(lambda x: str(x)[1:])


g_spend["cost"] = pd.to_numeric(g_spend["cost"])

output:
ValueError: Unable to parse string "59,399.37 "  at position 0
```

Not working

Comment: Dividing an object by a float requires that you typecast the object to float. Could you kindly try `code`(float)g_spend.cost / pd.to_numeric(g_spend.leads)`code`

Comment: thanks @MedoAlmasry,  how do I do that? also I am okay not having a float and changing the data type as needed, to keep as simple as possible

Comment: That won't wont because of the dollar sign.

Comment: `(float)something` looks more like `C` than `Python`.

Comment: Okay so I am assuming that the dollar sign in the cost is cuasing this entire column to be recognized as a string object, so let's start by removing that shall we, remove the dollar sign using this `data.iloc[4].str[1:]` which basically just replaces the whole column with the same values except for the very first character which is the dollar sign. After that use this to convert the whole column into numeric values `df["cost"] = pd.to_numeric(df["cost"])`

Comment: You could also use `df["cost"].astype(float)` to make the `dtype` of the column float. But you have to get rid of the dollar sign before.

Comment: @Valentino That's correct, I was too quick to answer that I didn't see that. AT) Peter Sorry for the confusion. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: @MedoAlmasry and Valentino.I removed the dolar sign now Im getting ValueError: Unable to parse string "59,399.37 " at position 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Remove the dollar sign

`data.iloc[4] = data.iloc[4].str[1:]`

Step 2:

`df['cost'] = df['cost'].str.replace(r'\,', '').astype(float`

Step 3:

`data["cost"] = pd.to_numeric(data["cost"])`

Comment: and Valentino.I removed the dolar sign now Im getting ValueError: Unable to parse string "59,399.37 " at position 0

Comment: Getting Key Error, means that addressing the column using it's name is not working
Try `print(data.columns.tolist())` to visually see the names of all columns, if they don't have names then you can access them via indices like data.iloc[4] instead of data["cost"]

Comment: ['id', 'Campaign_ID_name', 'Month', 'Account', 'campaignid', 'campaign_name', 'cost', 'leads']

@Medo not a key error: ValueError: Unable to parse string "59,399.37 "

Comment: Could you please elaborate when do you get that error?

Comment: The problem is the comma in "59,399.37". As such, you need to use the following `df['cost'] = df['cost'].str.replace(r'\,', '').astype(float)` in order to remove commas entirely